# How to guarantee uniqueness of analytic continuation of the zeta function

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

The Riemann zeta function has one analytic continuation to $\Re(s)>0$ given by:
$$\zeta(s)=\frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\{x\}}{x^{s+1}}dx \space \space (1)$$
It also has anther analytic continuation to the entire complex plane given by the function that satisfies the functional equation below:
$$\zeta(s)=2^{s}\pi^{s-1}\sin(\frac{s\pi}{2})\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(1-s)\space \space (2)$$
and there can be more analytic continuations derived for the zeta function.

So the question is how do I guarantee the uniqueness of the analytic continuation of the zeta function to the domain $\Re(s)>0$ ? Will the identity theorem be sufficient in this case or does the identity theorem will guarantee uniqueness only if analytic continuations are defined in the same domain so identity theorem may not be used to show that analytic continuation in (1) and (2) agree for $\Re(s)>0$

Comment: You can also turn the integral right away into a sum by using $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ and see what happens.

Comment: the identity theorem says that if $f,g$ analytic functions that are equal in an open set say, then $f=g$ wherever both are defined; any two analytic continuations of $\zeta$ will agree in $\Re s >1$ so they must be equal everywhere they are both defined

Comment: @TymaGaidash yea this will help for $\Re(s)>1$ ,however, for $\Re(s)<1$ it won't help as using $\{x\}=x-\lfloor x\rfloor $ will give us 2 diverging integrals

Comment: @Conrad yea i thought so too at first but in this article (https://math.berkeley.edu/~nikhil/courses/185.f15/1123.pdf) in the second page it says identity theorem only holds for 2 analytic continuations that have the same domain.

Comment: True and that what my comment above implies; so expliciting the comment, it means that if $f$ analytic on $A$ has analytic continuation $g$ on $B$ and $h $ on $C$ where $A$ is a subset of both $B$ and $C$ then $g=h$ on $B \cap C$ so in other words on the maximal domain where $g$ and $h$ are both defined; this of course doesn't mean that the definition of $g$ works on the whole of $C$ or that the definition of $h$ works on the whole of $B$, only on their intersection which already contains $A$

Comment: In the example above $B$ is $\Re s>0$ and $C$ is the whole plane, so the two expressions are equal on their intersection which is $\Re s>0$; this doesn't tell us anything about the integral in $(1)$ on $\Re s\le 0$

Comment: @Conrad yeah this makes sense but doesn't the article say otherwise? That it is not generally true that if $g$ is an analytic continuation of $f$ to $B$ and $h$ is an analytic continuation to $C$ then $g=h$ on $B\cap C$ ?

Comment: yes you are right - forgot to mention that one needs $B \cap C$ connected (or if you want $g=h$ agree on the connected component of $B \cap C$ that contains $A$ - that indeed is crucial, though here it applies since $\Re  z>0$ is connected( think of extending $\sqrt z$ from the open first quadrant by choosing the argument to lie in $(-\pi, \pi)$ vs in $(0, 2\pi)$ so getting extensions to the plane minus the negative or positive half-line respectively; the extensions match on the upper half-plane only ($\sqrt {-i}=e^{-\pi/4}$ in the first case, and $e^{3\pi/4}$ in the second!)

Comment: the proof is immediate $u=g-h$ on $B \cap C$ then $u=0$ on $A$ hence $u$ is zero on the connected component of $B \cap C$ that contains $A$ by the standard identity theorem ($f$ analytic on a domain and zero on an open set there then $f$ is zero on the domain); however we cannot say anything about $g-h$ on other components of $B \cap C$ that are disjoint form $A$ as we saw in the example above

Comment: @Conrad yea this makes sense now thanks for the clarification! But i have a question: if the domains $B$ and $C$ have poles like for example for the zeta function there is a simple pole in the analytic continuations at $s=1$ will the identity theorem hold for the domains $B$ and $C$ ? and will they be considered connected?

Comment: Poles are ok as the identity theorem holds for meromorphic functions too (meromorphic functions are analytic in an extended way if we think of their range being the Riemann sphere); in the plane removing a point doesn't affect connectivity of open sets so those sets are connected; note also that you can easily make a meromorphic function analytic in the regular sense by multiplying it with a polynomial in the case of finite poles like here so can use $(s-1)\zeta$ which is entire etc